# Is it possible to query list of package local types from system catalogue?

Tags: oracle

Trying to identify a way how to extract from system catalogue a list of package local types (i.e. types that are defined inside of  a package).

For example, I have defined following package specification (package body is omitted for now):

```
CREATE PACKAGE test_package AS
    TYPE TimeRec IS RECORD(
        Minutes SMALLINT,
        Hours SMALLINT);
    PROCEDURE test_subprogram(date VARCHAR2);
END;
```

I am able to get a list of subprograms that belong to `test_package` by querying `DBA_PROCEDURE` system view.

Would like to do the same but for package types but not able to find corresponding view. Can anybody suggest one, if exists (I hardly believe though that this info is not stored in catalogue)?

I for sure can extract package sources and look through it in order to identify which types are defined in there but this is not exactly what I need.

Limitations:

- access rights are restricted to SELECT only

Thanks for a help

Comment: ALTER SESSION SET plscope_settings='identifiers:all' ;  then compile your packages that you are interested in. Once done, look in all_identifiers view and looks for 'DECLARATION' in USAGE column. Note, this may be slightly different between versions but it should get you going.

Comment: @Raj, thank you for the advice. I've gave it a try and it worked for me in a test mode. However, in real time scenario I am restricted to SELECT access rights only, i.e. packages recompiling won't work for me.
Is there any other options how list of package local types can be retrieved?

Comment: if the code is same, it will be same in prod and non-prod environment.